# AndEngine GLES2 Low sprite quality after resize

Tags: android, andengine

I have a sprite 160x160 pixels (in attachment).

After resize sprite become unclear (right image).

How can I get normal quality (middle image)?

Thanks for help.

```java
BitmapTextureAtlas Texture1 = new BitmapTextureAtlas(null, 1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(Texture1);

ITextureRegion player = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(Texture1, this, "player.png", 0, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: In OpenGL, this effect is typically obtained using mipmaps, but I do not know how to use mipmaps in andengine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try other `TextureOptions` ?
They tell you how the AndEngine will interprete the pixels when resizing. You have the follwing options:

NEAREST   <-- pixels are visible
NEAREST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA 
REPEATING_NEAREST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA

BILINEAR  <-- a little blurred 
BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA
REPEATING_BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA

You currently use `BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA`, but if you don't care about the alpha-channel (transparency) you can simply use the `BILINEAR` or `REPEATING_BILINEAR`.
Play a little with these settings to find the best for your needs.

If you want to know more, here's  a [link](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/compare-4-type-of-textureoptions-t805.html) to a thread in the AndEngine Forum where these Options are explained in more detail.

regards 
christoph

Comment: Thanks for help.

I tried all Texture Options and BILINEAR PREMULTIPLY ALPHA is the best for me (because sprite has shadow).

I noticed that sprite quality depends of scale size. Less size - less quality.
Original image size is 160x160 pixels. If I set 50x50 pixels it looks pretty good.
But if I set 20x20 pixels it looks terrible.

However if original image size is 60x60 pixels and I set it to 20x20 pixels it looks good.